# Is it possible to control Heroku via a Node.js app (like the Heroku Ruby gem does)?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm used to being able to control my Heroku app instance using the Heroku gem. Is there a Node package that provides the same functionality? I would like to create some Hubot scripts for doing things like restarting my app.

Answer (score 2):

Just grab the source code (https://github.com/heroku/heroku) and look at the API calls and replicate this in your node.js code

Comment: thanks, will do. i was hoping that maybe someone had started this already.

Comment: i've actually only just discovered hubot - I have a bot that allows you to scale processes...needs cleaning up a little though.

Comment: @JohnBeynon this is exactly what we are looking to build, is your script somewhere? a gist?

Comment: i'll post back here when it's finished.

Comment: here ya go https://gist.github.com/1361213 - let me know how it works out for you. It may be rough around the edges, I'm no Node.js developer. It's only for controlling Cedar apps though.

Comment: That link fell down; does anybody have a copy?

Comment: Oh no, wait, GitHub is down, whodathunkit? :(

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing public AFAIK but the Heroku gem merely interacts with Heroku's (unpublished) REST api - I'm pretty sure it would be easy to reverse engineer the few calls you'd need from the existing Ruby Gem so you can perform similar actions via Node.

Comment: The Heroku REST API is not unpublished.  It's just not well documented.  There are other libraries that have been built against it.  But today the Ruby code is the best "documentation" of the API.